# gets rows from mysql where row elements date is between now & 5 days from now

Tags: mysql, date

I know this has prob been answered, but I've searched for almost an hour now and Im not finding my answer.

Here is my sql query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (`calendar_event`)
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`start_time`, '%m/%d/%Y')
    BETWEEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 5 DAY AND CURDATE()
```

Here is the format of the `start_time` column 06/30/2011 8:30 AM

The query isn't having any errors, Im just not getting any results...

Comment: Is start_time a datetime column? if so, why are you formatting it? and, you do realize  you have `INTERVAL 1 DAY` instead of `INTERVAL 5 DAY` in your code?

Comment: Your title says 5 days, your query says 1. Which do you mean?

Comment: Sorry... The 1 was an accident in this post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`BETWEEN a AND b`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) needs `b` to be greater than `a`, otherwise the interval is empty.

Try inverting the two date parameters you're building.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
WHERE date_col BETWEEN 'date1' and 'date2'